# cordova plugin install error if install from github

Tags: android, cordova, github

Im trying to install a private repository as follow from config file:

```
<plugin name="com.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation" spec="https://username:password@github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation.git#2.1.2" />
```

unfortunately i have got this:

Discovered plugin "com.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "com.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin com.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation@https://username:password@github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation.git#2.1.2 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.

And I got the same error with all plugins what came from github.
-The user and password should be ok, because I tested on github many times.